# When connecting to a merger node is there any reason to use a number other than 0 as the second argument if the input is not channel splitter

Tags: web-audio-api

I understand that when you connect a splitter to a merger you can do something like this:

```
splitter.connect(merger, 1, 0);
```

But when connecting an input source such as a stereo buffer source directly to a merger is there any reason *ever* to set the second argument of the connect method to something other than zero ? I assume the answer is no, but I'm not sure and looking for validation.

```
var stereoSoundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
stereoSoundSource.buffer = whatever;
stereoSoundSource.connect(merger, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Splitter is currently the only node that has multiple outputs, so it's the only node for which you would ever need to specify an output other than 0.

There *are* scenarios where you would do this with a splitter.  For example, imagine how to create a graph that flips stereo channels:

```
var merger = context.createMerger(2);
var splitter = context.createSplitter(2);

splitter.connect(merger,0,1);
splitter.connect(merger,1,0);
```

In the future, some other nodes might acquire other outputs (like, I've proposed using a separate output for the envelope in a noise gate/expander node), and then there might be other cases (and this answer would change).

Comment: I wasn't clear with my wording in the question.If you did this WITHOUT using a splitter. If you connected the input source such as a stereo file buffer DIRECTLY to the merge node would there be any reason to set the second argument to zero . I will reword my question for clarity

Comment: Ah.  Well currently splitter is the only node that HAS additional outputs (for a multi-channel node, like a stereo audio buffer, it's just additional channels, not additional outputs) - so if there's no splitter, then the answer is "no".  If/when nodes with additional outputs are added, then the answer would be yes, as above.  Will edit answer.